# LateX image doesn't show

Tags: graphics

Ok, I've got a image I want to insert into my report for college and when I compile the captions show but the images doesn't, the only thing I see is blank space enclosed by a borderline with the adress of the image inside.
Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{/home/pera/USP/Experimental III/Relatório I/Figuras}}
```

And the concerning part of the code:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{figarranjo2.eps} 
\end{figure}
```

Notice that I've already tried: compiling Latex/DVI-->PS, checking the folder of the figure, changing image format to png and compiling in PDFLatex and everything ends up at the same blank space... Actually I always have problems when it comes to images in LateX... Any suggestions?

Comment: The path with spaces and accented letter also will cause trouble along with the missing `/` at the end of the path.

Comment: I've searched before posting but none of the answers already there solved my problem, thought was much efficient posting the code. Actually the thing of removing the "draft" part really worked thx.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the `draft` option when you use `\documentclass[<options>]{article}`.